# Monodevelop Autocomplete any way to use spacebar to apply item

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, monodevelop

Is there any way to use the spacebar or the braces to apply the suggested item, like in VS?
eg. when I type Sys.Wi.Fo it would replace it with System.Windows.Forms

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are snippets. You can read aout them [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
I think the related mechanism in Mono is Code templates. It'll be worth your time to look [here](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Tasks/Source_Editing/Code_Templates) .

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think those are snippets, those are obtained from the assemblies using reflection. Snippets are common programming constructs like class or for... etc. My problem is that in MonoDevelop I have to use the Enter button to apply the suggestion, but I am used to the VS IDE where I can use any of the ( { [ ; Spacebar Enter keys to apply the suggestion to my code. Thanks

Comment: When you type, for instance, "cw (tab)" and get Console.Write that is a snippet (not the programming concept, but the VS.NET development tool). If you are referring to something else, I guess I misunderstood you.